# How do you get the file name of the data source of an Excel table into a cell?

Tags: excel, vba, datasource

I have table named "Materials", on the worksheet "Material Data", that gets its data from another workbook. I would like to be able to retrieve the name of the external workbook file ("data.xlsm") and show it in a cell. I'm having trouble finding where this is stored in the Excel VBA Object model.

```
Sub GetConnection()
   Dim ConSource As String
   Dim ws As Worksheet

   Set ws = Sheets("Material Data")

   ConSource = ws.ListObjects("Materials").QueryTable.Connection
   'ConSource = ws.ListObjects("Materials").QueryTable.SourceDataFile

   Worksheets("Quote").Range("A15").Value = ConSource

   ConSource = ""

End Sub
```

Neither the QueryTable.Connection nor the QueryTable.SourceDataFile properties have the external data source's file path stored in them. Where should I be looking?  Thank you!

EDIT: I also tried `.QueryTable.SourceConnectionFile`; it didn't have anything, either.

Comment: What is  `.QueryTable.SourceConnectionFile` ?

Comment: @CDP1802, sorry, I should have said, I tried that one, too, and it doesn't have anything, either.

Comment: Is `ws.ListObjects("Materials").SourceType` = 3 ?.

Comment: @CDP1802, yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not isolated in its own object property, but I did find the source file path by parsing the "Power Query M" formula string. The following code works:

```
Sub GetConnection()
    Dim conSource, powerQueryMFormula As String
    Dim formulaChunks() As String
   
    powerQueryMFormula = ThisWorkbook.Queries("Materials").Formula

    'Split the formula string at every double quotation mark.
    formulaChunks = Split(powerQueryMFormula, Chr(34), 3) 'Chr(34) = double quotation mark.
    conSource = formulaChunks(1)

    Worksheets("Quote").Range("A15").Value = conSource

    conSource = ""
    powerQueryMFormula = ""
    
End Sub
```